# How can one define a custom data object?

Tags: data-structures, design-patterns

In *Mathematica* there are different objects like `InterpolatingFunction` or `SparseArray`? How can I define a custom data object with special data structure?

**Example:**

```
f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}];
f // InputForm
```

returns us

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 6}}, {4, 3, 0, {6}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic}, 
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {5}, {8}, {5}}, {Automatic}]
```

But if one evaluates the above output one gets back

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{1, 6}}, <>]
```

I could not find any documentation how to do it for any custom data object that I want to define for my program.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Format is what you are looking for: Create a data structure, something like this:

```
mkMyData[d1_, d2_] := MyData[d1, d2]
GetD1[a_MyData] := a[[1]]
GetD2[a_MyData] := a[[2]]
Format[MyData[d1_, d2_]] := "MyData[<" <> ToString[Length[d1] + Length[d2]] <> ">]"
```

Call the constructor:

```
data = mkMyData[Range[5], q]
```

(*
    "MyData[<5>]"
*)

Call a selector:

```
GetD1[data]
```

(*
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
*)

Answer (score 14):

As Michael Pilat explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119830/618728) it is more robust to use `MakeBoxes`, rather than `Format`.

Using `MakeBoxes`:

```
MakeBoxes[diag[m_?MatrixQ], _] ^:= 
  InterpretationBox[RowBox[{"diag", "[", #, ",", #2, "]"}], diag[m]] & @@
    ToBoxes /@ {Dimensions[m], Diagonal[m]}
```

Here is a definition for handling `Part` extraction:

```
diag[m_?MatrixQ][[part___]] ^:= m[[part]]
```

Result:

```
mat = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];

diag[mat]
```

> ```
> diag[{5, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
> ```

```
diag[mat][[2]]
```

> ```
> {0, 2, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to handling Apply or Function for your example, ie. such that diag[mat]["Something"] would result specified result?

Comment: @Karolis I think you are looking for [(7999)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121)?  The formatting rule (with `MakeBoxes`) should be independent of other definitions so this form should still work, e.g. `diag[m_?MatrixQ]["Det"] := Det[m]` and then `diag[mat]["Det"]` evaluates to `120` just as `Det[mat]` does.