# Define parameterized function

Tags: function-construction, subvalues

I would like to be able to define the gain function of a system from its parameters. Specifically, I'd like to define a function that accepts two inputs, call them $b$ and $w$, and returns a function that accepts a single parameter, $v$ and returns 
$1/\sqrt{(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2 v^2}$ .

What's the right way to do this? Presumably I'd like to be able to write

```
gain[b,w][v]
```

to evaluate the function, with parameters b and w, at v. But I'd also like to be able to write

```
f[v_] = gain[b,w]
```

and have `f[v]` be the same as `gain[b,w][v]`.

Comment: Version 10 introduced ["operator forms"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56504/121) that make this syntax native to a number of built-in functions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only thing you have to change is the definition of the last line:

```
f = gain[b, v]
```

Then calling `f[v]` will be the same as `gain[b,w][v]`

In more explicit terms:

```
gain[b_, w_][v_] := 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2 v^2]

gain[1.1, 1][.3]

(* ==> 1.03307 *)

f = gain[1.1, 1]

(* ==> gain[1.1, 1] *)

f[.3]

(* ==> 1.03307 *)
```

Comment: It really is that simple. Thanks. Syntactically, what is gain[b_,w_][v_]? (I'm talking about syntax trees here). Is gain[b_,w_] itself a function? I'm just trying to figure out how to conceptualize this - I've always been somewhat confused about the difference between functions and symbols in this language.

Comment: Well, `gain[b_,w_][v_]` and `gain[b_,w_]` are _patterns_ that have definitions associated with them. As I started typing this, Mr. Wizard has posted a more in-depth discussion of where the actual function is stored. It's interesting to compare the output of `SubValues` applied either to `gain` or to a `gain2` defined with the single `gain2[b_, w_, v_] :=`. The latter has its definition stored in `DownValues[gain2]`.

Answer (score 34):

You are wise to be interested in this syntax.  It can significantly streamline code.
In my opinion it should be used more often.

There are two primary ways to build this kind of function: a SubValues definition, and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html).

Either form will let you define and use `f` as `f = gain[1, 2]`.

### SubValues

SubValues are created when you make a definition like this:

```
gain[b_, w_][v_] := 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2 v^2]

SubValues[gain]
```

> ```
>  {HoldPattern[gain[b_, w_][v_]] :> 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2*v^2]}
> ```

With this form you are not actually creating a function when you call `gain[1, 2]`.
*It simply sits unevaluated until the third argument is given*.

Unlike the `Function` method you retain full pattern capabilities with the additional arguments.  You can for instance define this, which would require `If` or `Switch` in `Function`:

```
f[a_, b_][n_?EvenQ] := a^b + n
f[a_, b_][n_?OddQ]  := b^a - n
```

### Function

The other common method is to actually build a `Function`:

```
ClearAll[gain]

gain[b_, w_] := Function[v, 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2 v^2]]
```

This definition is stored in `DownValues`:

```
DownValues[gain]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[gain[b_, w_]] :> 
>      Function[v, 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2*v^2]]}
> ```

With this form when you call `gain[1, 2]` you get this:

```
Function[v$, 1/Sqrt[(2^2 - v$^2)^2 + 1^2*v$^2]]
```

One important use for this form is when you need the additional arguments (in your example `v`) to be held unevaluated with `HoldAll`, etc.  The `SubValues` form cannot do this*, but the third argument of `Function` can:

```
stylePrint[style_] := 
 Function[expr, Print@Style[HoldForm@expr, style], HoldAll]

printRed = stylePrint[{18, Red, Bold}];

printRed[2 + 3 + 1^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This form is also superior if your function can be partially evaluated because the result of the evaluation can be incorporated into the `Function`, often using `With`.

### Additional notes

Be mindful of the fact that you can accidentally blend these forms in a potentially confusing way.  If you define a `SubValue` first (or later, if it is a form that does not evaluate on a pattern) and later a `DownValue` with the same pattern you may get unexpected results.

```
ClearAll[gain]

gain[b_, w_][v_] := 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2 v^2]

gain[x_, y_] := Sin[x y] + Cos[y/x]

gain[1, 2][3]
```

> ```
> (Cos[2] + Sin[2])[3]
> ```

This could be particularly confusing (or powerful) if you use a constrained pattern like `gain[x_Real, y_] := . . .` as you may have one pattern match in one case and the other in another.

---

While the two forms I show above are the most common and arguably best it is worth understanding that they are not exclusive.  Because heads evaluate first, including `x[y]` in `x[y][z]`, any definition for `x[y]` that returns a function can act upon `z`.  Here is `stylePrint` again, using neither `SubVales` nor `Function`:

```
stylePrint2[style_] :=
  Module[{fn},
    SetAttributes[fn, HoldAll];
    fn[expr_] := Print@Style[HoldForm@expr, style];
    fn
  ]
```

---

"Pure functions" with machine-size arguments can often be auto-compiled in a way that pattern-based definitions (`*Values`) cannot.  This is attempted by various functions such as `Map`, `Table`, and `Fold` as controlled by the values in `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]`.

Let us compare the performance of `SubValues` and `Function` using machine-size `Real` numbers:

```
g1[b_, w_][v_] := 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2 v^2]
g2[b_, w_] := Function[v, 1/Sqrt[(w^2 - v^2)^2 + b^2 v^2]]

Table[
  f /@ RandomReal[14, 500000] // Timing // First,
  {f, {g1[0.3, 0.7], g2[0.3, 0.7]}}
]
```

> ```
> {1.466, 0.078}
> ```

---

* I said that SubValues definitions cannot handle Hold attributes for the additional arguments.  Strictly this is true, but there are some clever workarounds, with limitations.  Please see these Q&A's for examples and further discussion:

- [Currying with *Mathematica*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686494/currying-with-mathematica)
- [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/544/121)