# Possible to scope an anonymous function within Module?

Tags: function-construction, scoping

This is my first question. I'm fairly new to *Mathematica* and completely new to SE, so I apologize if this question is trivial.

I'm working on a problem that requires a function to be redefined several times and applied to data.  My "function generator" (not sure if this is the proper application of this term) looks like this:

```
makeLine[{m_, b_}] := line = Function[{x, y}, y - m x - b]
```

The idea being that the program can call line several times and then redefine it and call it again.

I was hopeful that I could do something like this:

```
Module[{line}, makeLine[{1, 0}]]
```

to avoid defining line as a global function, but it doesn't work.

```
?line
```

> Global`line
>   line = Function[{x\$, y\$}, y\$ - 1 x\$ - 0]

So, is it possible to do this?  If not, can someone suggest an alternate construct that does essentially the same thing?

Comment: You might prefer to make the name an argument to makeLine. Could do via `SetAttributes[makeLine, HoldRest];
makeLine[{m_, b_}, line_] := line = Function[{x, y}, y - m x - b]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Daniel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) describes in a comment you could make the symbol to define a parameter of `makeLine`.  Just to show a different way I'll use a [SubValues pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121):

```
SetAttributes[makeLine, HoldAll]
makeLine[sym_][{m_, b_}] := sym = Function[{x, y}, y - m x - b]

Module[{line},
 makeLine[line][{5, 2}];
 Array[line, {5, 2}]
]
```

> ```
> {{-6, -5}, {-11, -10}, {-16, -15}, {-21, -20}, {-26, -25}}
> ```

However, it may be simpler to just define the symbol locally yourself:

```
ClearAll[makeLine]
makeLine[{m_, b_}] := Function[{x, y}, y - m x - b]

Module[{line},
 line = makeLine[{5, 2}];
 Array[line, {5, 2}]
]
```

> ```
> {{-6, -5}, {-11, -10}, {-16, -15}, {-21, -20}, {-26, -25}}
> ```

Comment: I cannot yet "+1" Mr. Wizard or I would.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`Block` works as you expect.

```
Block[{line}, makeLine[{1, 0}]]
```

`Module` probably does not work, because it will only fake scoping for values that appear literally in it's body (ie so called lexical scoping).

`Block` has "dynamic" scoping. More info [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html).