# Writing a function that returns a (usable) function

Tags: functions, function-construction, syntax

I am trying to create a function that returns Arnold's Cat Map of size *n* iterated *k* times. I can get something out of the `Function` command, but I can't figure out how to use that output as a function.

The non-iterated version of the problem is trivial. I define my mapping function:

```
G[x_, y_, n_] := Mod[{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}.{x, y}, n];
```

I want it to work with `ImageTransformation`, so I define an appropriate function for that:

```
CatMapStep[{x_, y_}] := G[x, y, side];
```

where `side` is calculated somewhere earlier. Now I can call ImageTransformation (let's say I have an image `kitty`):

```
ImageTransformation[kitty, CatMapStep]
```

Done. But what do I do if you want to iterate CatMap *k* times? Well, I can hard-code k:

```
CatMapFiveTimes[u_] := Nest[CatMapStep[u], u, 5];
```

And I discovered the `Function' command, but I can't figure out how to use it. What I would *really* like to do is create a function that takes *k* as an argument, and returns a function of *u*. Such is the sentiment of the following **incorrect** snippet:

```
IteratedCatMap[k_] := Function[u, Nest[CatMapStep[u], u, k];   <--- DOESN'T WORK
```

In my fantasy world, I would then be able to define CatMapFiveTimes by invoking the following line:

```
CatMapFiveTimes[u_] = IteratedCatMap[5];     <--- HYPOTHETICAL
```

And then using it as I would the previous definition.

How can I create this function that returns a function?

Thanks,
David

PS: Note that I am using Mathematica 8, although my officemate has Mathematica 9 and she couldn't get it, either.

PPS: I am *completely* open to a totally different approach to this problem. Ultimately, my only goal is to use `Manipulate` to let my students specify how many iterations of the cat map they want to see. I will be doing similar things for the Mandelbrot set, as well.

Comment: Define "doesn't work." What happens when you run it? The reason I ask is I've run your code, and I've seen what happens. But, you don't give enough info for the casual reader to know what the issue is.

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: [(7999)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps just a syntax problem:

```
side = 1;
kitty = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
G[x_, y_, n_] := Mod[{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}.{x, y}, n];
CatMapStep[{x_, y_}] := G[x, y, side];
CatMapFiveTimes[u_] := Nest[CatMapStep, u, 5];
it5 = ImageTransformation[kitty, CatMapFiveTimes];

IteratedCatMap[k_] := Function[u, Nest[CatMapStep, u, k]];
itt5 = ImageTransformation[kitty, IteratedCatMap[5]];

GraphicsRow@{it5, itt5}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Lena, oh Lena, please accept my apologies!

Comment: Damn. Should have noticed that small issue. +1, grudgingly. :)

Comment: @rcollyer Ha! Mma always finds a way to get me staring stupidly at a line of code for hours

Comment: I had a semi-colon issue once. A single misplaced semi-colon was fubaring about 500 lines of code, and I couldn't find the damn thing. Two syntax highlighters and Mr.Wizard's message tool later, I found it. But, it took much longer than I care to admit to.

Comment: This did it! Thank you!

Comment: Just saw this. Haven't you already been reported to the Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Centerfolds?

Answer (score 3):

This question is related to and possibly a duplicate of: [Define parameterized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121)

First there appears to be a mistake in your code; I believe you wanted:

```
CatMapFiveTimes[u_] := Nest[CatMapStep, u, 5]
```

To realize your `IteratedCatMap` we do not need to generate a function, merely to use a `SubValues` pattern definition (as discussed in the link above).

```
IteratedCatMap[n_][u_] := NestList[CatMapStep, u, n]
```

I have used `NestList` above in place of `Nest` simply to make the operation of the function visible.

With our supporting definitions in place:

```
G[x_, y_, n_] := Mod[{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}.{x, y}, n];
CatMapStep[{x_, y_}] := G[x, y, side];
side = Prime @ 50;
```

To use this you simply write:

```
IteratedCatMap[5][{62, 35}]
```

> ```
> {{62, 35}, {159, 97}, {186, 27}, {170, 213}, {95, 154}, {115, 20}}  (* five + original *)
> ```

You can define your "function" like this:

```
CatMapThreeTimes = IteratedCatMap[3];

CatMapThreeTimes[{62, 35}]
```

> ```
> {{62, 35}, {159, 97}, {186, 27}, {170, 213}} (* three + original *)
> ```

Note that the value of `CatMapThreeTimes` is not a function, it is simply a head waiting to be completed before the SubValues rule triggers.

You can use [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) as also discussed in the linked question:

```
IteratedCatMapAlt[n_] := NestList[CatMapStep, #, n] &

CatMapTwoTimes = IteratedCatMapAlt[2];
```

The value of `CatMapTwoTimes` *is* a function (a pure function, specifically).

---

### Notes

- It is generally a good idea to avoid starting user Symbol names with capital letter, especially short or generic names like `G` because these may conflict with `` System` `` Symbols now or in the future.
- Beware creating function that rely on a global definition such as `side`.  It is often better to include such a parameter as an argument, possibly using SubValues as discussed above.

To illustrate the second point you might write your functions like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

G[side_][{x_, y_}] := Mod[{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}.{x, y}, side]

catMap[side_, n_][u : {_, _}] := Nest[G[side], u, n]
```

You can then create a particular version of the "function" simply with:

```
catMap4 = catMap[229, 4];
```

And use it:

```
catMap4[{62, 35}]
```

> ```
> {95, 154}
> ```

Comment: Thank you! So would this be more computationally efficient than the Nest approach, because the new function is not actually generated? I don't have a very good sense of how Mathematica evaluates things. The function was actually named \Gamma, but I couldn't paste the Greek letter, so I decided to change it to G. I will keep that in mind about the global parameters. Is there a book on Mathematica programming that's reasonably concise and informative?