# Define a matrix depending on variable in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, variable-definitions

I am translating my code from Python to Mathematica. I am trying to define a matrix, whose values depend on a variable chosen by the user, called kappa. In Python the code looked like that:

```
def getA(kappa):

    matrix = zeros((n, n), float)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            matrix[i][j] = 2*math.cos((2*math.pi/n)*(abs(j-i))*kappa)
    n = 5
    return matrix
```

What I have done so far in Mathematica is the following piece of code:

```
n = 5

getA[kappa_] :=
A = Table[0.0, {n}, {n}];
For[i = 0, i < n, i++, 
  For[ j = 0, j < n, j++, 
   A[[i, j]] = 2*Cos[(2*pi/n)*(abs (j - i))*kappa]]]; 

b = getA[3]
```

But when I try to evaluate this matrix for a value of kappa equal to 3, I get the following error:

```
Set::partd: "Part specification A[[i,j]] is longer than depth of object.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Unlike Python mathematica's lists go from 1 to n

Comment: BTW you could have filled your table directly without initialization and without `For` loops using `Table`.

Comment: I have changed my code into:

Comment: n = 5
   getA[kappa_] :=
   A = Table[0.0, {n}, {n}];
   For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
     For[ j = 1, j <= n, j++, 
      A[[i, j]] = 2*Cos[(2*pi/n)*(Abs[j - i])*kappa]]]; 
    b = getA[3]

Comment: but I get a matrix of 0.0 elements only. How is it possible?

Comment: @Kuba what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Here is what I get: getA[kappa_]:=A=Table[0.,{n},{n}]

Comment: ClearAll[getA];getA[kappa_,n_] :=Table[ 2*Cos[(2*pi/n)*(abs (j - i))*kappa],{i,n},{I,n}];

Comment: Look up `Table` in the documentation and do not use `For`.  Check the examples for `Table` in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

```
n = 5;
getA[kappa_] :=
 Table[2*Cos[(2*π/n)*(Abs @(i - j))*kappa], {i, 0, n-1}, {j, 0, n-1}] 
getA[3] //MatrixForm
```

[image]

You may post the expected result from your Python code in order to make it easier finding a functional programming equivalent.

EDIT, clean up:

```
getA[n_,kappa_] :=
 Table[2*Cos[(2*π/n)*(Abs @(i - j))*kappa], {i, 0, n-1}, {j, 0, n-1}] 
getA[5,3] //MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 1):

For highest efficiency, you should use the [`Listability`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) of built-in functions in order to construct lists. Using this, you can do the following one-liner:

```
a[n_, kappa_] := 2 Cos[(2 Pi/n) kappa Abs[Array[Subtract, {n, n}]]]

a[5, 3] // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc} 2 & \frac{1}{2} \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) \\ \frac{1}{2} \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & 2 & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) \\ \frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & 2 & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) \\ \frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & 2 & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) \\ \frac{1}{2} \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1+\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{2}   \left(-1-\sqrt{5}\right) & 2 \\\end{array}\right)$$

The important thing here is that the `Array` which makes the matrix is actually deep **inside** all the actual functions from which the matrix elements are built. By doing this, each time a new function is applied to the list we get the speed advantage of the compiled listability of that function, instead of having to call the function for each individual matrix element.

Answer (score 0):

1. As written your definition stops after the first "line" ending with `;`
2. You should use [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to localize your variables.
3. *Mathematica* is case-sensitive and System Symbols will always start with capitals
4. Function application uses square brackets: `Abs[j - i]`
5. Indexing begins from one
6. generally you should pass `n` as a parameter

These issues corrected:

```
getA[n_, kappa_] :=
 Module[{A, i, j},
   A = Table[0.0, {n}, {n}];
   For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
    For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, A[[i, j]] = 2 Cos[2 Pi/n*Abs[j - i]*kappa]]
   ];
   A
 ]

getA[5, 3]
```

However as [penguin77](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27290/penguin77) already showed there are better ways to write this in *Mathematica*.  Usually `For` should be avoided.  See:

- [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)

For example:

```
fn[n_, kappa_][i_, j_] := 2 Cos[2 Pi/n*Abs[j - i]*kappa]

Array[fn[5, 3], {5, 5}]
```

This uses a SubValues definition; see: [Define parameterized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121)

Comment: @user27673, Indeed once getting used to functional programming, For loops appear awkward. Can only encourage all M users to use functional programming for it's efficiency, readability and last and not least, elegance