# Using Nest on a function that takes a function as one of its arguments

Tags: recursion, core-language

I have a function, `nS[f_, xk_]`, which takes as arguments a function `f` and a vector `xk`. It works perfectly when I use it on its own.

```
nS[t, {1, 0, 0}]
```

> ```
> {0.664063, 0.417969, 0.}
> ```

But when I try to use `Nest`, for some reason it won't evaluate the function:

```
Nest[nS, {t, {1, 0, 0}}, 1]
```

> ```
> nS[{t, {1, 0, 0}}]
> ```

And if I increase the iterations on Nest I just get `nS[nS[nS[...]]]`.

Comment: You can add an additional definition for your function `nS[{t_, list_}] := nS[t, list]`, your problem right now is that you have nothing defined for `nS[{...}]` only `nS[..]`.

Comment: moreover, what is returned from first nest won't fit `nS` later for more repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

Because you do not provide definitions for `nS` an `t`, I can not provide a solution based on your code, so I will contrive my own example.

```
f[fnc_, data_List] := fnc /@ data
sq[x_] := x^2

f[sq, Range @ 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 9}
> ```

Now to use `f` with `Nest`, I simply write

```
Nest[f[sq, #] &, Range @ 3, 3]
```

> ```
> {1, 256, 6561}
> ```

The 1-st argument of `Nest` is a function of one variable, the list that `f` requires, so the 2-nd argument can be that list alone.

The auxiliary function `sq` makes the code easier to understand but isn't actually needed. The `Nest` expression can just as well be written with pure functions.

```
Nest[f[#^2 &, #] &, Range @ 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your examples shows your function outputting a simple numeric vector is not not make sense to apply your two-argument function to this result.  Presumably you want to keep a constant `f_` parameter for every application of `nS`.  The best way to do that is to [define a parameterized function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/121):

```
nS[f_][xk_List] := Developer`PartitionMap[f, xk, 3, 1]
```

Basic use is almost the same:

```
nS[Total][Range@5]
```

> ```
> {6, 9, 12}
> ```

And now you can just write:

```
NestList[nS[Total], Range[9], 4]
```

> ```
> {
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
>  {6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24},
>   {27, 36, 45, 54, 63},
>    {108, 135, 162},
>     {405}
> }
> ```

Comment: is Developer'PartitionMap documentation easy to find? using phone without full range of characters.

Comment: @ubpdqn Yes, if you mean is it easy to find after you know about it: just enter `PartitionMap` in the documentation search field.  If you mean is it easy to find if you've never heard of it then it a bit more work but still not hard: from the main documentation page click **Standard Extra Packages** which takes you to a page that includes **Developer Utilities** of which `PartitionMap` is a member.

Comment: ok stupid question but seems like a useful function I did not know about and some functions have variable quality documentation...am nowhere near computer so helpful answer wrt exploring other of the many functions unknown to me...

Comment: @ubpdqn I believe it has uniformly the same syntax as `Partition` with the exception of the added first parameter that is a function to map over the partitions.