# What kind of creature is h[c] for definition h[c_][x_] := (* function of x and c *)

Tags: functions, syntax

To implement "Hero's Method" for approximating $\sqrt{c}$, one iterates the function `(x + c/x)/2` for a given number `c` (e.g., `2`) starting with some initial value of `x`. This can be implemented by defining first the function

```
g[c_, x_] := (x + c/x)/2
```

of two variables, next fixing the first variable to get the pure function `g[2, #]&`, and finally iterating with `Nest` (or `NestList`, etc.):

```
Nest[g[2, #]&, 1.0, 5]
```

Another way is to define

```
h[c_][x_] := (x + c/x)/2
```

and then iterate `h[2]`, as in:

```
Nest[h[2], 1.0, 5]
```

Yet `h[2]` evaluates to nothing more than itself:

```
h[2]
(* h[2] *)
```

*Technical question*: What kind of creature is the expression `h[2]`? It acts *as if* it were a function. Can one say something more to describe or characterize it? (Yes, I realize that [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is involved here.)

Subsidiary *pedagogical question* (which may be unsuitable for this forum):  For a *Mathematica* beginner, which approach to iterating (for a fixed `c`) is likely to be easier to understand — fixing the first argument to `g` and making a pure function, on the one hand, or defining `h` as shown, on the other hand? How does the answer to the technical question affect the answer to this pedagogical question?

Comment: Try `h[2][y]`...

Comment: This is "Heron´s method", not "Hero´s method" - even he must have been a clever guy ;-)

Comment: Actually, the method is widely cited as "Hero's Method", e.g. in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots. And it's also knows as the" Babylonian method". But yes, the English transliteration of the Greek name Ἥρων" is "Heron".

Comment: @ciao: Yes, I know what I get for `h[2][y]` or `h[2][x]`, etc. But how can one characterize `h[2]` itself? That was my question.

Comment: It is simply an expression which by itself does not get rewritten non-trivially,  so stays inert. It is not different from any other expression that doesn't have global rewrite rules applicable to it. You can make it behave as a function, however. Technically, this is realized via `SubValues`. This allows you to pass the "arguments" collected in `h` (like `2` in this case), to the body of the "function" (r.h.s. of the rule). This is useful, since it allows you to separate parameters which are fixed externally (behaves like constants, `2` here), from those which are passed dynamically.

Comment: @murray One useful thing here is to think how would you alternatively implement such a construct. If you want it to have exactly the same semantics, you can do something like `h[c_]:=Function[x, (x + c/x)/2]`. This reveals that you create a closure, closed over the value of `c`. So, this is one way to think also about `h[c][x]` construct when defined with rules, from the functional programming (operational) viewpoint - although the mechanism is technically very different.

Comment: Closely related, perhaps duplicate: [Define parameterized function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7999/245)

Comment: @Jens: the "closely related" post you cite tells me something I already know, namely, that `SubValues[h]` gives what I expect. But it still doesn't say anything about what `h[2]` *is*.

Comment: I think a good way to rephrase my technical question is to ask: "How would you explain to a *Mathematica* beginner what the object `h[2]` is?"

Comment: @murray That depends on what the meaning of "is" is...

Comment: To give a short answer, I would say that for practical purposes it really is appropriate to call `h` a **parametrized function**, where `2` in `h[2]` is the parameter value. That has explanatory value to the extent that it allows you to remember when it's used, even if it doesn't describe the technical subtleties.

Comment: @Jens: Yes, I definitely like calling `h` a "parameterized function", with the `2` in `h[2]` a value of the parameter. I'm beginning to sense that it makes little sense to ask what `h[2]` *is* other than to say it's a function and look at `h[2][x]` or `h[2][1]`, etc. -- no more sense than to ask what, say, `Sin` "is".

Comment: @mgamer, both "Hero" and "Heron" are in fact acceptable; the same situation applies with his triangle area formula.

Comment: If one is going to regard `h` as a parameterized function, i.e., a family of functions, then one might as well use a subscript definition: `Subscript[h, c_][x_] := (x + c/x)/2`, so that StandardForm notation such as $h_2$ resembles  a traditional mathematical notation for one of a family of functions.

Answer (score 6):

This is pitched at the "how to understand" level, not the "how is it implemented" level. I've basically presented how I think of these things, without really caring about how Mathematica carries them out.

The object `h[2][x]` is just another expression-with-head. The head is `h[2]`, which just happens to have a more complicated form than is perhaps usual. In the same way, `Function[{x}, 5 x][4]` is an expression whose head is `Function[{x}, 5 x]`. In this case, the complicated head is so complicated that Mathematica actually has a replacement rule to deal with its simplification.

To understand it more completely, it might help to meditate on the result of `f[4] /. f -> h[2]`. Structurally, the expression is basically identical.

I prefer to do both of your options: I would define `g` in two ways simultaneously.

```
g[c_, x_] := (x + c/x)/2
g[c_] := g[c, #]&
```

or for the second line

```
g[c_][x_] := g[c, x]
```

This more closely mimics the `Select[function][list]` forms introduced in 10.2, which are forms I use a lot and very much like.

It also has the benefit that simplification can be performed one time only. For instance, suppose $f(c, x)$ required a costly computation for each $c$, but it was fast to analyse as $x$ varied. I'm thinking `LinearSolve`, for instance. Then the following form is very neat.

```
f[c_, x_] := f[c][x]
f[c_] := f[c] = Function[{x}, (* time-consuming thing *)]
```