# How to re-parse (or re-map) character '.' to user-defined function

Tags: function-construction, custom-notation

The default behavior of the character `.` between two non-numeric characters is to be interpreted as the infix of the *Mathematica* function `Dot`.

Is there a command that can be placed in a package to get the front-end to parse `.` as an infix for another function -- say user-defined one, `myDot[]`?

That is,

1. `a.b` should be interpreted as `myDot[a, b]`
2. `myDot[a.b]` should map to `a.b`
3. `Dot[a,b]` should not get mapped to `a.b`, but the functionality of the built-in function `Dot` should not be lost.
4. `3.14` should remain a single number, where here the dot indicates a decimal separator.

Comment: Now I understand your nickname

Comment: Related: [(117)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117/121), [(16652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16652/121), [(27081)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27081/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Updated*

First, let's stop `Dot` from creating these box structures.

```
MakeBoxes[Dot[x__], form_] := 
 RowBox[{"Dot", "[", RowBox@Riffle[MakeBoxes /@ {x}, ","], "]"}]
```

Next, let's specify that these structures should instead be interpreted as `myDot`:

```
MakeExpression[RowBox@(row : {PatternSequence[_, "."] .., _}), form_] := 
 MakeExpression[
  RowBox@{"myDot", "[", RowBox@Riffle[row[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]], ","], "]"}, form]
```

The slicing and riffling is ugly... there is probably a cleaner way to do it. `ReplacePart` seemed to be doing weird things when I tried it but I didn't spend any time on it.

The last step is to specify that `myDot` should also be rendered into the same structure:

```
MakeBoxes[myDot[x__], form_] := RowBox@Riffle[MakeBoxes /@ {x}, "."]
```

Now,

```
Dot[a, b, c]
```

> Dot[a, b, c]

```
Dot[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]
```

> a x + b y + c z

```
a.b.c
```

> a.b.c

```
a.b.c // FullForm
```

> myDot[a, b, c]

```
{a, b, c}.{x, y, z} // InputForm
```

> myDot[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]

```
a.(b^2).c
```

> a.b<sup>2</sup>.c

```
% // InputForm
```

> myDot[a, b^2, c]

In all cases you will have to use `MakeExpression` to override the interpretation of user input, but you may also find `TagBox` and `InterpretationBox` interesting alternatives to the `MakeBoxes` implementations above.

Comment: We posted at exactly the same time.  I mean to the second.  Look at the time-stamp. :O

Comment: I think one may want to test the elements of `RowBox` to make sure they are Symbols, assuming that is what QuantumDot wants.  This is the purpose of `symbolQ` in my answer.  For example should `99 .bar` (note the space) be read as `Dot[99, bar]` or `myDot[99, bar]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard All the cool kids post at the same time. Good point about testing for symbols. I didn't think about that very hard -- it could get messy otherwise.

Comment: I just noticed your edit; that won't work.  The pattern `a_Symbol` will not match as the Symbols are still in String form, e.g. `"foo"` rather than `foo`, hence the somewhat baroque `symbolQ` in my answer.  I suggest you put it back to the way it was; perhaps the original is even the behavior that QuantumDot wants.

Comment: Sigh, I always make that mistake. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @mfvonh This looks like what I need!  But there are few issues:  Inputing `x.y^2` leads to some problems with rendering the boxes.  Do you know how to fix it?  Also. `Dot[x,y]` leads to `x.y`.  But I'd like `Dot` not to get changed to `.` .  Do you know how to stop this behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: @QuantumDot See update; does that get you all the way?

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing that you intend for a transformation into `myDot[a, b]` rather than `myDot[a.b]` and I will answer accordingly.  Different output formatting would remain possible.

There is not much that you can do to affect the *parsing* of code as that is handled by the Front End before even [`CellEvaluationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellEvaluationFunction.html) is called.  To see how an expression is parsed you may use the method given by John Fultz  in answer to my question:

- [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121)

For example:

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute @ UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]

"3.14 + foo.bar / 22 - Dot[x,y]" // parseString
```

> ```
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"3.14", "+", RowBox[{RowBox[{"foo", ".", "bar"}], "/", "22"}], "-", 
>     RowBox[{"Dot", "[", RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}]}]], StandardForm}
> ```

We can see that `foo.bar` is *already* parsed differently from `3.14` and `Dot[x,y]` therefore, fortunately, we do not need to change parsing to effect your modification.  Instead we can operate on this Box data.

Here is a basic implementation using [`$PreRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$PreRead.html):

```
symbolQ[s_String] := MatchQ[ToHeldExpression@s, Hold[_Symbol]]

$PreRead = # /. 
    RowBox[{a_?symbolQ, ".", b_?symbolQ}] :> 
     RowBox[{"myDot", "[", RowBox[{a, ",", b}], "]"}] &;
```

Now:

```
3.14 + foo.bar / 22 - Dot[x, y]
```

> ```
> 3.14 - x.y + 1/22 myDot[foo, bar]
> ```

If you want to add output formatting for `myDot` please read:

- [How can one define a custom data object?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2590/how-can-one-define-a-custom-data-object/2616#2616)

Then ask for help as needed.

Comment: Very helpful!  This is in the direction of precisely what I need.  There is a strange effect that I need help understanding.  Suppose (in v 9.0.1) I am now manipulating the expression in the following way: `3.14 + foo.bar/22 - Dot[x, y] /. myDot[x_, y_] :> x@y`, I get the expected result.  But look what happens when I surround the rule with braces: `3.14 + foo.bar/22 - Dot[x, y] /. {myDot[x_, y_] :> x@y}`.  I get a *ToExpression::sntxi:* error message, although the replacement is still successful.  Do you know how to understand the origin of that error?

Comment: @QuantumDot That appears to be the result of a poorly conceived `symbolQ`. (i.e. my mistake.)  Let me start by asking if it `symbolQ` is even necessary: is it okay for non-Symbol terms in `term1.term2` to be interpreted as `myDot[term1, term2]`?  Number forms such as `3.14` will *always* be interpreted as numbers regardless.

Comment: Hmm... now that I think about it, the answer is actually no; it is not necessary, and probably wiser to always map `.` to `myDot`.  The original reason for requiring that the arguments be symbolic is that if the objects on both sides of `.` had head `List`, then it should proceed to operate as built-in `Dot` on the two lists.  But I realize this can be confusing to the users, and users would anyway fall back on explicit use of `Dot` to sum the products of list elements.

Comment: Next, I tried to format the output of `myDot`.  Following the link at the end of your answer, I came up with `MakeBoxes[myDot[arg1__, arg2__], _] ^:= InterpretationBox[RowBox[{arg1, ".", arg2}], myDot[arg1, arg2]]`.  The problem with this is that (1) `myDot[a,b]` leads to `Global'a.Global'b`.  How do I get rid of the `Global` context?  and (2) `myDot[a,b^2]` leads to error message "An unknown box name (Power) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression."  Do you know how I can allow more complicated structures inside `RowBox`?

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is too easy, but `\[CenterDot]`, or <kbd>Esc</kbd>`.`<kbd>Esc</kbd>, is all set up for use as an infix operator, with no need to mess with box structures or confuse the user by changing the built-in meaning of `.`.

You can just set

```
CenterDot = myDot
```

and then call

```
a·b
(* myDot[a, b] *)
```

Comment: Nice alternative, +1,  But esc-dot-esc is two too many key-strokes for me

Comment: Fair enough. The other drawback is that unicode characters aren't friendly if you want to edit the code in a .m file.

Comment: There's one other problem: the `CenterDot` character has too much space on either side.  If the font designer had kept the spacing the same as that of the ordinary `Dot`, I think I would have opted for your alternative.

Comment: @QuantumDot You could do: `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases, "."}] = 
 RowBox[{"\[InvisibleSpace]", "\[CenterDot]", "\[InvisibleSpace]"}]` to shrink the space.