# Is there an easy way to let mathematica print out every Erfc and InverseErfc as F and F^{-1}

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Mathematica uses complementary error function and its inverse as functions for example when integral of a Gaussian is taken. Therefore, all output expressions of Mathematica involve Erfc and InverseErfc, if needed.

My question is: If there is an easy way to manipulate mathematica so that it outputs CDF of standard normal Gaussian distribution for Erfc and inverse CDF of standard Gaussian for InverseErfc?

I used the following and it should be working BUT I am not able to verify this!

```
Unprotect[Erfc];
Unprotect[InverseErfc];

Erfc[x_] := 2*(1 - f[x*Sqrt[2]])
InverseErfc[x_] := -ff[x/2]/Sqrt[2];
```

and then I use

```
FullSimplify[1/2 (1 - p0) Erfc[(-((Sqrt[n] (μ0 - μ1))/σ) + 
 Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[
   2 (1 + 1/
       2 (-2 + 
         Erfc[(Sqrt[2] n (μ0 - μ1)^2 - 
           Sqrt[2] σ^2 Log[(-1 + p0)^2/p0^2])/(
          4 Sqrt[n] (μ0 - μ1) σ)]))])/Sqrt[2]] + 1/2 p0 (2 - 
 Erfc[(Sqrt[2] n (μ0 - μ1)^2 - 
   Sqrt[2] σ^2 Log[(-1 + p0)^2/p0^2])/(
  4 Sqrt[n] (μ0 - μ1) σ)])]
```

and I only guess that the output is correct. But I connot confirm it. When I define later on

```
f[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
ff[x_] := InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
```

I got problems. Is the way I follow sound? How can I justify that Mathematica indeed fullsimplified correctly, I mean in terms of $f$ and $ff$.

Comment: Since `CDF[NormalDistribution[]]` includes `Erfc`, you're now defining `f` in terms of something which itself is now defined in terms of `f`.  This can only lead to problems.  Maybe use a replacement rule like `{Erfc -> (2 f[-Sqrt[2] #] &)}`?

Comment: I would like to point you to a similar question I wrote about a different function `Dot`.  I hope it will help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63147/how-to-re-parse-or-re-map-character-to-user-defined-function

Answer (score 1):

One complete overkill solution to the problem might be to use the [Notation Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html).

Comment: page does not exist. More explicitely?

Comment: Sorry - try now. I'm new to stackexchange markup.