# Can we make preread replacements in an *.m* file before being run?

Tags: customization, parsing, command-line, input-forms, development

This the second question of [(152743)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152743/can-we-make-new-definitions-for-inputform-in-packages), the preamble of which is reproduced here:

> Those who don't have/prefer the front end of *Mathematica* will either use a plain ASCII editor to write a script in an `.m` file or just use *Mathematica* directly from a command-line terminal.  In either case, everything must be supplied in `InputForm`.
>
> When working with a *Mathematica* package, commonly used symbols/functions might be excessively verbose in `InputForm`, and certain shortcuts/aliases would be greatly desired.  Examples of built-in `InputForm` shortcuts are the infix operators `+` (`Plus`), `-` (`Minus`), ... and `.` (`Dot`).

Two questions that arise as a package developer:

1. [(152743)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152743/can-we-make-new-definitions-for-inputform-in-packages)
2. Is there something analogous to `#define` of C and C++ that can be placed at the top of an `.m` file that instructs the kernel to make replacements of literal occurrences before the lines are read?  (this issue may be easily bypassed if question 1 is answered.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  In fact, even `$PreRead` is ignored when reading .m files.

What you can do is define a myGet as

```
myGet[file_] := Module[{str},
    str = Import[file,"Text"];
    str = myTextReplacemeansts[str];
    ToExpression[str];
]
```

to make your own substitutions.

Comment: Dang.  OK, I'll wait for others to provide other possible solutions.

Comment: Hmm..  I'm finding that `$Pre` and `$PreRead` are not observed when using  *Mathematica* from a command-line terminal.  Are `$Pre` and `$PreRead` strictly front-end functions?

Comment: It shouldn't be restricted to the FE, but I'm seeing the same behavior.  Time to file a bug report...

Comment: Actually, `$Pre` is working fine, it's only `$PreRead` is broken.  Are you use `$Pre` isn't working for you?  Try `$Pre=Echo`.

Comment: Here is a work around.  If you launch the kernel with the `-rawterm` option, it will fix `$PreRead`, though that will disable the arrow keys.  On Linux (and probably on OSX using homebrew or similar), you can use the `rlwrap` program as wrapper around the kernel to restore the arrow OKs

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't paying attention; `$Pre` actually does work on my system.  I'll try the `-rawterm` option to see if it fixes `$PreRead`; **EDIT** yes it does work.  Also, it allows me to enter special characters, too.  (I was wondering why I couldn't do that before).